# Format the `with`-expression setter block on the same line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

How can I specify in an `.editorconfig` that there shouldn't be a newline before the setter block of a C# record's `with`-expression? In other words, this:

```cs
var foo = new Foo("abcd");
foo = foo with {
    Bar = "efgh"
};

public record Foo(string Bar);
```

instead of this:

```cs
var foo = new Foo("abcd");
foo = foo with
{
    Bar = "efgh"
};

public record Foo(string Bar);
```

Ideally, I would want that Visual Studio should also respect this value in the `.editorconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [open bug in Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49312) and is scheduled to be fixed in Visual Studio 16.9.